# How to read the config file as an input when running the python code from command line

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, python-unittest

I have multiple test classes and a basetest class in python.
test classes inherits from basetest class.

I want to run the test class from command line and it needs some input parameters, these input parameters should be stored in a config file. This config file can be provided as an input from the command line.

How can I achieve this to provide it from command line and then parse the config file. I need parsing to happen in the basetest class because this will be used for all the test classes.

Test Class: You can ignore the content if they don't make much sense as it is just a sample class

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class TestCase():

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def test(self):
        baseUrl = "https://www.google.com"
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(baseUrl)
        elementByXpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']")

        if elementByXpath is not None:
            print("We found an element by XPATH")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
    result = unittest.TestResult()
```

BaseTestCase:

```
class BaseTestCase():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        # In the setup() or __init__(), config file should be parsed
        self.login.login("admin", "admin")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.log.info("Driver quit, session closed")
```

The file that will be run from the command line will be the test class.
Something like this:
python testcase.py --configfile

I am pretty new to python, any help in this is highly appreciated.

I used to work with Java and TestNG, where it's really easy. We can provide any configurations in the TestNG xml file itself.

I am using unittest from python, any suggestion on which framework can be better other than unittest will also be great.

This is for a GUI Test Framework and I need to run tests on different browsers and platform.

Comment: Use a 'ConfigParser' to parse a configuration file. For multiple browsers and platform try using either something like BrowserStack or manually assign workers on a Jenkins instance.

Comment: Providing some more information about what you want to parse would certain help you get the right response.

Comment: @a_bhi_9 I need to parse the values in the config file then provide them to base test class, the values would be browser name, operating system name or even anything that I only want to use in the base test class
Browser stack and Jenkins can't do anything if the code does not know which browser to bring up.

Comment: Make a ´.cfg´ or ´.ini´ file with all the config you need. Then use ´ConfigParser´ lib to parse it. I think you should refer to the Python documentation try to write some parser code and if it doesn't work out ask for more help.

Comment: @a_bhi_9, sorry I think  you didn't understand the question. I know about ini file and config parser. I have already written one. What I was trying to ask is, where do I read the values from the .ini file. I need to run the test using python unittest __main__() method. Which place .ini file would be read and how to provide that file from command line. Then how can I pas those values to BaseTest because I need the values from it in BaseTest.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hierarchy as below.

```
`
|
|- TestModule
       |
       |- main.py (your entry point to the test)
       |- conf.ini
       |- parse_config.py
```

Now here, you in the `parse_config.py` you call your `SafeConfigParser` on the `conf.ini`. Pass its path as a string to the config parser.

Instantiate the class which you make in the parse_config file in the setup (or either before_all hook) of the test runner.

```
class ParseConfig(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = None
        ....

    def parse_file(self):
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read("config.ini")
        self.base_url = parser.get("section", "url")
        ....
```

Hope you get a rough idea of what is to be done

**EDIT**

In the `parse_conf.py`

```
import argparse

class ParseConfig(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = None
        self.file_name = None

        self.parse_cli()  # This will parse the config file name from CLI
        self.parse_file() # This will parse the config file whose name you provide

    def parse_cli(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Parse conf file")
        parser.add_argument("--conf", "-c", metavar="Conf", help="Config file name")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        self.file_name = args.conf

    def parse_file(self):
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read(self.file_name)
        self.base_url = parser.get("section", "url")
        ....
```

In your `main.py`

```
from parse_config import ParseConfig
...
...
ParseConfig().parse_cli()
ParseConfig().parse_file()
...
...
```

This way you can have multiple configuration file names parsed.

Now call your script like,

```
python main.py -c conf.ini
```

Comment: I want to provide configuration file from command line (I mentioned this). If I have one configuration file with defined value, there is no point in having one. I want the framework to be flexible, so that it can read the file that I provide from outside.
I will have many test files and one basetest which can do all setup. From where I can provide the config file, so that I can run all test files?
Setup should only be done in one place, basetest.

Comment: Using the same principle, use the ArgumentParser to parse the file name which you pass through the command line and then using config parser parse the given file. Need some code?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can put some example as an answer, it will help me understand what you are trying to explain